# How do I save Google API credentials in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api

I feel stupid. I get the authorization code, and am able to access the drive API at the moment, which is what I almost want.

I want to be able to access the API offline, but I still don't understand how am I supposed to save the credentials.

My question is, what am I supposed to put inside this method?

```
# Store OAuth 2.0 credentials in the application's database.
#
# @param [String] user_id
#   User's ID.
# @param [Signet::OAuth2::Client] credentials
#   OAuth 2.0 credentials to store.
def store_credentials(user_id, credentials)
  raise NotImplementedError, 'store_credentials is not implemented.'
end
```

So I can later run:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization = credentials
client = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')
client
```

Without having to ask the user for permission again

Comment: Typically, with OAuth when you get the user's permission to access the resource you get a "token" back that allows you to access that resource as that user. I haven't used the Google APIs, but if it is OAuth 2.0 as you state in your comments than you should just be able to store the token.

Comment: Are you using a database?

Comment: no, I want to hard code it.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it to an file:

```
def store_credentials(user_id, credentials)
   File.write 'credentials.data', [user_id, credentials].to_json
end
```

and later read it from that file:

```
require 'json' 
user_id, credentials = *JSON.parse(File.read('credentials.data'))
client.authorization = credentials
```